# How do I add a lens (focal) blur to an image

Tags: image-processing, blur, gaussian

I'm trying to figure out how to do this programatically, but despite all of my Googling I cannot figure out how this is down.

The lens blur is different than the Gaussian blur which looks very computer generated.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried? I implemented a gaussian blur filter in Matlab some time ago and found [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) pretty helpful.

Comment: That's kind of the problem -- I know how to write a script for the Gaussian blur but I cannot find information on the focal/lens blur.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't read the question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state what language you're after, but Java can do a lot of image processing, check out this link:

[jhlabs blurring examples](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html)

It even includes the lens blur effect you are after.

Comment: I'll need to implement it in multiple languages.  That resource you linked is very helpful though, particularly this statement: "What we do is take the image and the kernel, and perform the Fourier transform on them both. We then multiply the two together and inverse transform back."

Answer (score 3):

I found an [interesting blog post](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=1495) on the subject. I haven't read through the whole thing, but it seems quite descriptive and might be of some help.